# Cannot link an IBOutlet for UITextField

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, iboutlet

I tried adding my an outlet on my Main.Storyboard and CTRL + dragged it into my corresponding view controller.

```
class LoginViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var nameField: UITextField!
}
```

Upon doing this, I am getting this error

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<UIViewController 0x7f7ff051e860> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key nameField.'
```

What could be causing this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is that it's creating an instance of `UIViewController`, not an instance of `LoginViewController`. You can tell because the error message says `<UIViewController 0x7f7ff051e860>`, not `<LoginViewController 0x7f7ff051e860>`. Since `UIViewController` doesn't have a `nameField` outlet, you get an error when the storyboard loader tries to connect that outlet.

There are two likely explanations:

1. The custom class in the storyboard isn't set to `LoginViewController`. Select the view controller in the scene in your storyboard. From the menu bar, choose View > Utilities > Show Identity Inspector. Then, in the Identity Inspector (right-hand pane), make sure the class is set to `LoginViewController`.

   [image: setting the custom class]

   You must have set the custom class at some point, if Xcode let you connect the outlet. But you might have accidentally undone the change afterward.
2. The file containing the `LoginViewController` source code isn't part of your target (your app). In this case, there should be another message earlier in your debug console, like this:

   ```
   2016-02-08 22:08:04.569 test[3049:9594499] Unknown class _TtC4test16MyViewController in Interface Builder file.
   ```

   To fix this, open your `LoginViewController.swift` file (or whatever file contains that class). From the menu bar, choose View > Utilities > Show File Inspector. In the File Inspector (right-hand pane), find the Target Membership section and turn on the checkbox next to your app.

   [image: adding to the target]

Comment: The second problem was my issue! I reconnected the Target Membership and deleted some previous outlets and this fixed the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this is that you still have an invalid outlet connected to your `UITextField` in interface builder.

Select your label in interface builder and click on the arrow icon in the far right panel, and check that you haven't got any extra 
referencing outlets in there.

[image]